# Are child windows destroyed automatically if -1 is returned from WM_CREATE?

Tags: c, winapi

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(msg)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
        {
            HWND hStatic1, hStatic2;
            hStatic1 = CreateWindowEx(0, L"Static", L"", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD, 4, 20, 40, 40, hwnd, 0, GetModuleHandle(0), 0);
            hStatic2 = CreateWindowEx(0, L"Static", L"", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD, 4, 80, 40, 40, hwnd, 0, GetModuleHandle(0), 0);
            return -1;
        }
        break;

    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Are child windows created in WM_CREATE destroyed automatically when -1 is returned? Will hStatic1 and hStatic2 be destroyed automatically when I return -1 or do I need to call `DestroyWindow()` on each one of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All child windows are destroyed when a window is destroyed, and this includes when a window is destroyed during its creation by returning `-1` from `WM_CREATE`.

Comment: Is returning -1 from WM_CREATE when a child window fails to create usual behavior or is it better to continue creating the rest of the child controls?

Comment: @Rm32a It depends how critical that child window is I guess.

Comment: Indeed. For dialogs, this is controlled by the Dialog Window Style `DS_NOFAILCREATE`. As a developer, there is certain advantage to enabling it: It allows you to see *which* control's creation failed.